# using linq with WMI collection

Tags: c#, linq, garbage-collection, wmi

I have doubts about releasing IDisposable objects.

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"))
{
    using (ManagementObject item = s.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Last())
    {

    }
}
```

Should I also put collection from s.Get() into using?

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection items = s.Get())
    {
        using (ManagementObject item = items.Cast<ManagementObject>().Last())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Does linq dispose collection (s.Get()) from my first block of code in this topic?

```
s.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Last()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Multiple objects can be used in with a using statement, but they must
>   be declared inside the using statement

So I would expect those two sets of using blocks to be equivalent. However, while  [ManagementObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection.aspx) implements IDisposable [ManagementObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx) does not and the documentation for using also tells us:

> The object provided to the using statement must implement the
>   IDisposable interface. This interface provides the Dispose method,
>   which should release the object's resources.

So, since the using block can't dispose of the ManagementObject resources anyway, you don't need ManagementObject in its own using block and can use

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection items = s.Get())
    {
        ManagementObject item = items.Cast<ManagementObject>().Last();
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

To be honest since `items` and `item` are scoped within the using block you probably only need

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"))
    {
        ManagementObjectCollection items = s.Get()
        ManagementObject item = items.Cast<ManagementObject>().Last();
        //do stuff
    }
```

That should free them for GarbageCollection so while you don't know that `items` has its Dispose method called at the end of the using block it will be called on the next collection.

Comment: This is not how `using` works.  When it says "inside the `using` statement", it means the part inside the `( )`, not inside the (optional) `{ }`.  The "multiple objects" it mentions are such that `using (Stream foo = File.OpenRead("Foo.dat")) using (Stream bar = File.OpenRead("Bar.dat")) { }` can be rewritten as `using (Stream foo = File.OpenRead("Foo.dat"), bar = File.OpenRead("Foo.dat")) { }`; it does **not** mean `items` and `item` in your 2nd snippet will be disposed by the `using` (they won't).  Also, `ManagementObject` _does_ implement `IDisposable` by way of deriving from `Component`.